# PHP - Threading - Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found

Tags: php, multithreading, compiler-errors

I am trying to run this program:

```
class AsyncOperation extends Thread
{
   public function __construct($threadId)
   {
      $this->threadId = $threadId;
   }

   public function run()
   {
      printf("T %s: Sleeping 3sec\n", $this->threadId);
      sleep(3);
      printf("T %s: Hello World\n", $this->threadId);
   }
}

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $t[$i] = new AsyncOperation($i);
   $t[$i]->start();
}
echo microtime(true) - $start . "\n";
echo "end\n";
```

I followed directions and did the following:

1) Extracted the zip

2) Moved php_pthreads.dll to the c:\xampp\php\ext\ directory.
Move pthreadVC2.dll to the c:\xampp\php\ directory.

3) I open c:\xampp\php\php.ini and added the extension=php_pthreads.dll

I'm still getting this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in C:\PHP\TwitterBSTest\threadtest.php on line 10